# What about offering a badge for using advanced search options?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, search

I think any means to make users use the search option reduces the number of duplicate questions. Therefore, I propose to encourage its use.

Comment: I already saw "robo-editing" for getting the Strunk&White ...

Comment: I don't think they would get lucky even with the "advanced" search options for finding duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is an interesting idea, I would suggest to not make the change for the following reasons:

- Many duplicates are from new users who don't care or don't even know about badges and reputation. (Many of them don't even accept answers.)
- There is not a good way to track if a person searched in order to prevent a duplicate.  What would be the criteria for the badge?  100 searches?  Would a user who searches for "bob" and then asks a duplicate question about SQL get credit toward the badge?
- I think either punishing with negative reputation for duplicate questions or making the search box larger for new users would be a better investment.

Comment: Yes, I think dupes should have a -2 (i.e. equivalent of a down vote by default)

Answer (score 7):

Users who don't know that they should search before asking won't know that there are badges either.

Searching before asking is a common etiquette of all online communities and is better known to general public (i.e. new users) than badges.

Besides, I thought that badges were to be awarded for promoting good behavior. This would be promoting the absence of bad behavior.

It's like giving someone award for *not* robbing a store. It is expected behavior, not exemplary good.

Comment: +1 for 'It's like giving someone award for not robbing a store. It is expected behavior, not exemplary good.'